# How to read the current document in Word VSTO?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

How do you read the current document (as a byte array or OOXml string) from a Word VSTO Ribbon button?

**Without**, having to save the current file to disk, and reading that file back from disk.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You have a VSTO Word Add-in, I take it... You want to click a button and... what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous... Consider adding more details. In the meantime, hope this will help.

You can access the document using 
`Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;`

To get the OOXML you can use:
`string XML = doc.Content.WordOpenXML;`

If you want to open a document you can use:
`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(fileFullName);`

Comment: and the negative vote is because...? it is worth leaving a comment when downvoting at least I can improve/delete my answer.

Comment: Not sure why you got the down-vote - your answer was exactly what we needed.